# My HP-Vista based laptop has become very slow recently

Tags: windows-vista, laptop

My HP laptop which has Vista Home premium. When I try to start Firefox, internet explorer, it becomes very slow. No other app. When i checked the Performance in Task Manager. It shows the Physical memory , Free as 0 bytes, almost always. This has been recently. Earlier it didn't used to be zero. Laptop has 2GB of RAM. I have nothing running in my tray except - Sound control, Laptop power plan indicator,Network status indicator.

[image]

There are no other processes whose memory usage adds up to so high to make Free memory as 0.
[image]

Then what could be hogging the memory and make the laptop very slow.

Any pointers would help as it is crawling at the moment.

Comment: I would test with Opera (It's lightweight) but since you doesn't seems to use a lot of system memory, I would just reinstall the whole system from scratch. You will spare a lot of time!

Comment: I can't explain the memory usage (except to ask what you see when you click the "Show processes from all users" button), but when is the last time you defragmented? A highly-fragmented disk could slow program startup by quite a bit.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a few FireFox plugins disable them.

Comment: Yes, even the plugin-container process seems to be quite much memory user. How do u disable plugins in firefox.

Comment: Go to Tools - Addons
From there go to plugins and disable each, one by one and see which is causing the problem.  You may want to check out the extensions section also.

Answer (score 0):

Vista allocates memory for faster performance and can release any of this cached memory if another program needs it, and is very efficient at managing memory, so I don't think this is the issue.

I suspect malware. After you follow the steps below, do an IE reset using Internet Options Advanced Tab, then clean out your IE temporary Internet files and user temp files folder.

Follow the order given below to disinfect your PC.

Make a boot AV disc then boot from the disc and scan the hard drive, remove any infections it finds, I prefer the Kaspersky disc myself. The New 2010 Kaspersky disc can update the AV dat files if you are connected to the internet at the time of scan and is suggested to update before the scan.
http://www.techmixer.com/free-bootable-antivirus-rescue-cds-download-list/

Then:
Install free MBAM, run the program and go to the Update tab and update it, then go to the Scanner Tab and do a quick scan, select and remove anything it finds.
http://download.cnet.com/Malwarebytes-Anti-Malware/3000-8022_4-10804572.html

When MBAM is done install SAS free version, run a quick scan, remove what it automatically selects.
http://www.superantispyware.com/download.html

These last 2 are not AV softwares like Norton, AVG etc they are on demand scanners that only scan for nasties when you run the program and will not interfere with your installed AV, these can be run once a day or week to ensure you are not infected. Be sure you update them before each daily-weekly scan.